# UIImage+Resize.h - wrong affine transformation given for UIImageOrientationUp orientation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

For the UIImage resize I used the following class.

http://iphone.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/UIImage+Resize.m

But I am having issues in some iPhone orientation where I keep the phone in lined with a vertical surface. It does the resize properly but the image is not properly affine transformed. The image orientation is different. I logged the messages in the "transformForOrientation" method where it called the UIImageOrientationUp where I do not see any manipulation done to that orientation. I believe that's the reason for me to get an invalid transformation. So I need a help to fix this issue. Is there any "CGAffineTransformTranslate" or "CGAffineTransformRotate" to add in order to get the correct output.

Please advise me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(CGRect)bounds;` method in UIImage+Resize method doesn't take into account the orientation of the image.

Within that method, replace this line:

```
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

with this:

```
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:self.imageOrientation];
```

Comment: This is an one year old. However I was able to fix that using an alternative but I cannot remember that. BTW thanks for the reply.